# Azure Application High Availability

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, high-availability, azure-eventhub

I'm working in IoT enterprise application, where we have created all resources in South Central US. Recently (9/4/18) I noticed South Central US was down for long business hours due to any reason.

Now I'm trying to find best possible solution for high availability when a complete region down.

We are using following Azure resources.

> EventHub (telematic data ingestion)
>
> Azure Functions (EventHub, CosmosDB, ServicesBus Trigger)
>
> Web App & WebJob (Schedule and continuous)
>
> ServiceBus (Queue & Topic)
>
> Application Insight (Application logs)
>
> Storage Account (EventHub checkpointing and other data)
>
> Cosmos DB
>
> VSTS (CI/CD)

For Cosmos DB I know the solution, what should I do for other resources?

I don't see any way to create EventHub or ServiceBus multi-region cluster.

Answer (score 1):

There's no cluster arrangement for ServiceBus & EventHub but can set up a fail-over flow for both.

Please refer to these articles on MS Docs:

[Azure Event Hubs Geo-disaster recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-geo-dr)

[Best practices for insulating applications against Service Bus outages and disasters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters)

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing useful links. My application receives message from azrue function and webJobs and still, I need to figure out how to switch application when the primary namespace is down.

Answer (score 1):

Azure provides Availability Zones and Geo Disaster Recovery support for both Service Bus and Event Hubs.

Here is the link for Availability Zones for [Service Bus](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2018/06/22/azure-service-bus-is-now-offering-support-for-availability-zones-in-preview/) and [Event Hubs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eventhubs/2018/06/21/azure-event-hubs-is-now-offering-support-for-availability-zones-in-preview/)

For Geo Disaster Recovery, look into [Service Bus DR](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2018/01/31/geo-disaster-recovery-available-in-portal/), [Event Hubs DR](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eventhubs/2018/03/28/azure-event-hubs-geo-dr-configurations-now-enabled-in-all-azure-regions/)

Comment: how to switch azure function and webJobs to secondary namespace when the primary is down?